# Map inside LogLinearPlot with legends and different colors

Tags: plotting, legending

I have been trying to use Plot with a nested map to make plots of a numerically integrated function with different argument parameters, and after some searching I have finally got that sorted.  My MWE looks like this:

```
colors = (("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
    Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", ListLinePlot])) /. 
Directive[x_, __] :> x);
f[x_, y_] := y Sin[y Log[x]]
Plot[Map[f[l, #]/l &, {0.05, 0.1, 0.2}], {l, 0, 100}, Evaluated -> True,
 PlotStyle -> colors, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f", "f=y Sin(y ln(x))"}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[colors, {"y=0.05", "y=0.1", "y=0.02"}]]
```

[image: example]

Which works beautifully, but now I want to plot something in the same way but with a logarithmically scaled x-axis.  LogLinearPlot obviously does this but doesn't accept an "Evaluated" argument, and I can't figure out how to get the lines to all have a different color.

Is there a method which does this and is portable across all incarnations of *Plot function?

Comment: Wrap the first argument of your plot in `Evaluate`, i.e. `Evaluate[Map[...]]`, or equivalently `Evaluate@Map[...]`. You will also want to change the range for the `l` variable so it doesn't include $0$ for a logarithmic plot.

Comment: Nope... That breaks things completely and I get an empty graph

Comment: `LogLinearPlot[#, <options>] & @ Map[f[l, #]/l &, {0.05, 0.1, 0.2}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @telemin Did you remove the `Evaluated` option though? I posted what I see below as an answer, with the addition of Evaluate and the change in plotting domain to accommodate the logarithmic axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
colors = 
  (("DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
     (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", ListLinePlot])) /. 
        Directive[x_, __] :> x);
f[x_, y_] := y Sin[y Log[x]]

LogLinearPlot[
  Evaluate @ Map[f[l, #]/l &, {0.05, 0.1, 0.2}], {l, 1, 100}, 
    (*notice the removal of zero, which won't work in LogPlot*)
  PlotStyle -> colors, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "f", "f=y Sin(y ln(x))"}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[colors, {"y=0.05", "y=0.1", "y=0.02"}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]